# How to display name from one Form to another

Tags: vb.net

I dimmed a variable

```
Dim StudentName as String
```

When the user inputs their name in the TextBox I have:

```
txtName.Text = StudentName
```

This should save the data input by the user into `StudentName`.
On `Form3` Load I have the `StudentName` data display on the `Label` as

```
lblnameout.Text = Form1.StudentName
```

But it always comes out blank. How do I make it so that the name shows?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a `module` and set it as the startup object.  Declare your variables to be used globally there.  Outside of that, you could store and retrieve the values using application settings.

Comment: @user2366842, you can certainly use a module to declare a global variable in but there's no need or even good reason to make that module the startup object.

Comment: That is backwards. Should be `StudentName = txtName.Text` From MS docs "The = operator assigns the value on its right to the variable or property on its left."

Comment: huh.  I was originally taught to set it as a startup object.  Wonder if who told me that was misinformed.  I'd personally rather go the application settings route anyways, as you're really dealing with application values anyways if you're passing them between forms.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
txtName.Text = StudentName
```

should be the other way around:

```
StudentName = txtName.Text
```

Otherwise, you'll be replacing what the user typed in with what is already in the variable, which would be `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with the module route, but you can declare it as a Public Shared string and then modify it as needed. Under `Public Class Form1` place this line:

```
Public Shared StudentName As String
```

[image]

Now that you have a global variable, you just need to swap the values around like jmcilhinney suggested so the user data gets applied to the string.

```
StudentName = txtName.Text
```

[image]

Now you can go over to `Form3` and set your label up to retrieve the value of that string with:

`lblnameout.Text = Form1.StudentName`